# Why diagonal map is closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

can you help me?...

Let X $\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an algebraic set, and $f, g:X\rightarrow k$ two regular functions. If $X$ is irreducible and an open $U \subseteq X$ exists such that $f_{|U} = g_{|U}$, prove that $f=g$.

I have been able to prove that:

Let E be the subset where $f = g$ so E is closed (Why? I know that $E = (f,g)^{-1}(\Delta_{k})$ but... why is $(\Delta_{k})$ closed?). So $U \subseteq E \Rightarrow \bar{U} \subseteq \bar{E}=E$ (beacuse E is closed) $\Rightarrow X \subseteq E$, because $\bar{U}=X \Rightarrow E = X$ and $f=g$ in X.

Comment: The question posed in the title needs to be given its own context.  The body here is indeed copied from the earlier Question you asked, so if you want to settle this subproblem (a reasonable approach) frame it more carefully:  the diagonal map of *what*??

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta\subset X\times X\subset \mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{A}^n=\mathbb{A}^{2n}$.

Suppose the coordinates of $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$ are $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots, y_n.$ And $X$ is defined by $f_1,\ldots, f_m$.

Then $ X\times X$ is defined by $f_1(x),\ldots, f_m(x),f_1(y),\ldots, f_m(y)$  where $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n),y=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$.

And $\Delta$ is defined by $f_1(x),\ldots, f_m(x),f_1(y),\ldots, f_m(y),x_1-y_1,\ldots, x_n-y_n$. Hence it is closed.

Comment: Oh, careful here!! The Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$ is *not* the product $\mathbb{A}^n\times\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: That's unimportant here- as a product in the category of varieties, $\mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{A}^m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$

Answer (score 0):

The set of all regular functions is a *field*, and given regular functions $f:V\to k,\;g:W\to k$, the difference $f-g:W\cap V\to k$ is also regular, and in particular continuous. Now $$\{x|f(x)=g(x)\}=(f-g)^{-1}(0),$$and the latter is closed, as $\{0\}\subset k$ is closed in the Zariski topology.